# Bootstrap CSS conflict in joomla module

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, joomla-module, joomla3.4

I am creating a joomla module which uses bootstrap to style the various input fields. In my module's default.php file, I have incorporated bootstrap via the normal css link `<link type="text/css" src="http://mylink.com/modules/mod_mymodule/css/bootstrap.min.css">`. This works well with a non-bootstrap template but with a template which does use bootstrap, certain elements of the template do not display properly as a result of the bootstrap css file I have linked in my module. If I unlink the bootstrap file in my module, the input elements in my module are not responsive and the display of the module is just horrible.

My question is, how will I be able to incorporate bootstrap to my module without distorting the display of a bootstrap enabled template and also have my module displaying perfectly in a non-bootstrap template?

Comment: Can you post a url with all the code in question or supply a jsfiddle to your post showing your html at least? That way we can see if there's some sort of inheritance issue. For example, if you call Bootstrap twice you could have issues, if you override bootstrap and then call bootrap again that override will get wiped out.

Comment: The module is installed in http://demo.skibzy.com/tnt. It is the contact us form in the sidebar

Comment: To see what I mean, using the inspect elements option in the browser, remove the bootstrap css file that is right above the beginning of the form and note the changes in the login form and the search input at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the Joomla site I am using uses Bootstrap 2.3.2. Simply had to style my form to match the existing bootstrap file